# Issues creating multi-level dictionary with for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested

Here is my code:

```
dDict = {'Managers':colnames}


for elements in range(len(colnames)):
    dDict.update({'Managers' : {str(colnames[elements]): {str([[item for item in row] for row in sarr[elements]]) : {str([[num for num in r] for r in varr[elements]])}}}})
print(dDict)
```

colnames is a list of 71 asset manager names. sarr is a list of symbols, varr is a list of values associated to each symbol. The list of symbols is a list of lists, where each list contains a list of symbols associated to the asset manager. I am trying to create a multi-level dictionary that orders all of this in the appropriate order.

This is my output:

```
{'Managers': {"['Yacktman Asset Management']": {"[['P', 'E', 'P'], ['S', 'Y', 'Y'], ['P', 'G'], ['D', 'I', 'S'], ['M', 'S', 'F', 'T'], ['G', 'O', 'O', 'G'], ['N', 'W', 'S', 'A'], ['B', 'K', 'N', 'G'], ['C', 'T', 'S', 'H'], ['K', 'O']]": {"[['5', '.', '9', '5', '%'], ['5', '.', '4', '4', '%'], ['5', '.', '4', '1', '%'], ['5', '.', '2', '8', '%'], ['5', '.', '0', '7', '%'], ['5', '.', '0', '3', '%'], ['4', '.', '7', '6', '%'], ['4', '.', '5', '1', '%'], ['4', '.', '4', '2', '%'], ['4', '.', '3', '4', '%']]"}}}}
```

As you can see, only my last colname element is being printed, so update is a mistake, the elements of each list are being accessed strangely ("[['P', 'E', 'P'],) and they are not key/value paired.

How do I return the output:

```
{'Managers': {"Yacktman Asset Management": 
             {"PEP : 5.95%", 
              "SYY : 5.44%", etc.}}
             {"AKO Capital":
             {"LIN : 12.44%",
              "BKNG : 7.88%", etc.}} }
```

The following would be even better if possible-

```
{'Managers': {"Yacktman Asset Management": 
             {"PEP" : {"5.95%", "additional value"}, 
              "SYY" : {"5.44%", "add val"}, etc.}}
             {"AKO Capital":
             {"LIN" : {"12.44%", "add val"}
              "BKNG" : {"7.88%", "add val"}, etc.}} }
```

I hope this question is not too basic/elementary- I've been busting my brain on this for a while and I would really appreciate it if I could get some help because I'm certain this is more of a semantic issue than anything. For some additional information on my end goal- I'm trying to create a Multi-Index Pandas DataFrame off of this dictionary. If there is a better/easier way to go about this, given the three lists, please let me know.

Comment: If your variable `sarr` is a list of strings, then `[[item for item in row] for row in sarr[elements]]` will take the string in the position `element` (say, "MSFT") and then make a list of each string (say, "M","S","F","T").

Comment: @Kris Thank you. What would I use instead of `[item for item in row]`  to access `LIN` out of, say, `[[PEP,SYY],[LIN,BKNG]]` ? If I was doing it outside the loop it would just be `sarr[1][1]` - how is that done in a list comprehension? When accessing `sarr[elements]` it returns `[PEP,SYY]`.

Comment: Could you give me a sample of each list so I can see what you're working with? I feel like there is a better way to reach your end-goal of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @Kris thank you for your reply- I found a way to solve my problem and create the data frame, which I have added as an answer. If you are still interested however, I have also included in my answer sample code for each list, and some background on how I have obtained this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is great, but I like to let `pandas` do as much of the heavy_lifting as possible when it comes to stuff like this. For example, the following should also work nicely.

```
df_combined = pd.DataFrame()
for i,name in enumerate(colnames):
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Tickers'] = sarr[i]
    df['Values'] = varr[i]
    df['Fund Names'] = name*len(sarr[i])
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_combined,df])
df_combined = df_combined.groupby(['Fund Names','Tickers']).first()
df_combined
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense and is definitely a much simpler solution. I didn't know that groupby could work that way. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
varr = np.array(vals, dtype='object')

sarr = np.array(symbol, dtype='object')

zarr = []

bigDic = {}

for x in range(len(varr)):

        zarr.append(list(zip(sarr[x],varr[x])))

def convert(a):

        it = iter(a)

        res_dct = dict(it)

        return res_dct

for x in range(len(zarr)):

        bigDic[(colnames[x][0])] = convert(zarr[x])

dfB = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(bigDic, orient="index").stack()

display(dfB)
```

And here are some samples of the data I'm working with, if anyone has a better solution to constructing a multi index from this data.
output of `print(sarr, varr, colnames)`

array of lists sarr (ticker symbols):

```
[array(['LIN', 'BKNG', 'EBAY', 'V', 'EL', 'GOOG', 'NKE', 'RACE', 'OTIS',
       'PG'], dtype=object)
 array(['GRA', 'WRK', 'RL', 'UNVR', 'EPC', 'OI', 'LEA', 'AVT', 'EMN',
       'NOMD'], dtype=object)
 array(['BRK.B', 'WM', 'CAT', 'CNI', 'WMT', 'ECL', 'CCI', 'FDX', 'UPS',
       'SDGR'], dtype=object)
 array(['LOW', 'CMG', 'QSR', 'HLT', 'A', 'SBUX', 'HHC'], dtype=object)
 array(['FTCH', 'DXC', 'AMZN', 'DM', 'SFIX', 'OMF', 'ADT', 'FB', 'BABA',
       'VRM'], dtype=object)
 array(['CBRE', 'GOOGL', 'ALLY', 'CHTR', 'C', 'FB', 'BAC', 'STZ', 'COF',
       'NFLX'], dtype=object)
 array(['JOE', 'BAC', 'BRK.B', 'CNQ', 'T', 'KMI', 'CINF', 'ENB', 'WES',
       'CVS'], dtype=object)
 array(['IEP', 'OXY', 'CVI', 'HLF', 'LNG', 'NWL', 'NAV', 'CLDR', 'XRX',
       'HRI'], dtype=object)
 array(['MSGE', 'VIAC', 'GS', 'LAZ', 'ORCL', 'SNA', 'NLSN', 'MOS', 'ZBH',
       'WU'], dtype=object)
 array(['NEM', 'BRK.B', 'LKQ', 'BRK.A', 'WU', 'WFC', 'ATGE', 'GOLD', 'CDK',
       'SINA'], dtype=object)]
```

Array of values associated to tickers, varr:

```
[array(['12.44%', '7.88%', '7.12%', '6.59%', '5.40%', '4.84%', '4.63%',
       '4.32%', '4.06%', '3.96%'], dtype=object)
 array(['18.95%', '14.69%', '11.70%', '11.51%', '10.72%', '10.63%',
       '9.29%', '8.01%', '3.35%', '1.15%'], dtype=object)
 array(['43.71%', '9.84%', '9.18%', '8.35%', '7.49%', '4.23%', '3.80%',
       '3.52%', '3.41%', '2.47%'], dtype=object)
 array(['19.88%', '16.10%', '15.30%', '14.85%', '14.49%', '10.77%',
       '8.62%'], dtype=object)
 array(['5.16%', '4.62%', '4.29%', '4.21%', '4.17%', '3.90%', '3.30%',
       '3.24%', '3.07%', '2.87%'], dtype=object)
 array(['10.68%', '10.53%', '6.50%', '6.49%', '6.00%', '5.23%', '5.05%',
       '5.02%', '4.92%', '4.77%'], dtype=object)
 array(['90.79%', '1.19%', '1.12%', '0.93%', '0.90%', '0.70%', '0.68%',
       '0.67%', '0.62%', '0.61%'], dtype=object)
 array(['56.01%', '7.65%', '5.29%', '4.91%', '4.84%', '4.63%', '3.67%',
       '3.63%', '3.33%', '1.49%'], dtype=object)
 array(['6.38%', '5.79%', '5.47%', '5.40%', '5.20%', '5.18%', '4.92%',
       '4.47%', '4.24%', '4.19%'], dtype=object)
 array(['16.47%', '13.41%', '11.57%', '9.90%', '8.56%', '7.17%', '6.14%',
       '3.69%', '3.55%', '3.55%'], dtype=object)]
```

And finally, list of fund names aka colnames:

```
[['AKO Capital'], ['Alex Roepers - Atlantic Investment Management'], ['Bill & Melinda Gates Foundation Trust'], ['Bill Ackman - Pershing Square Capital Management'], ['Bill Miller - Miller Value Partners'], ['Bill Nygren - Oakmark Select Fund'], ['Bruce Berkowitz - Fairholme Capital'], ['Carl Icahn - Icahn Capital Management'], ['Charles Bobrinskoy - Ariel Focus'], ['Charles de Vaulx - International Value Advisers']]
```